# Displaying Django Messages Framework Messages

Tags: django, django-templates

I have been using the [Django Messaging Framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) to display messages to a user in the template.

I am outputting them to the template like this:

```
<ul>
    {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This outputs all the messages, errors, warning, success etc.
I was just wondering if anyone had any ideas how to display only the error messages something like:

```
<ul>
    {% for message in messages.errors %}
        <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The best I have come up with so far is this:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
            {% if message.tags == 'error' %}
                <div class="error">
                    <ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}

        <li>{{ message }}</li>

        {% if forloop.last %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

You can put an ifequal:

```
<ul>
    {% for message in messages.errors %}
        {% if 'error' in message.tags %}<li>{{ message }}</li>{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The mapping of message level to message tag can be configured with [MESSAGE_TAGS](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#id1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that means that I have to iterate through the errors several times to output all the errors and then all the success messages. I wanted a way to grab all the errors by themselves.

Comment: The docs say you have to iterate through all messages anyway or you will have them left over.

Answer (score 5):

A bit of a faff, but you could probably achieve this by adding a custom template context processor (cf. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/ ) -- something like

```
def collect_error_messages(request):
    messages = get_messages(request)
    error_messages = [ m for m in messages if 'error' in m.tags]
    return {'error_messages': error_messages}
```

then add that to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS list in settings.py, and then in templates you can do:

```
<ul>
    {% for message in error_messages %}
        <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You could do a variation on the same to build a dict mapping error level to message, and then iterate through each dict.

Answer (score 5):

Reto's answer works for me in this way

```
{% for message in messages %}
    {% if 'success' in message.tags %}

        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
            <strong>Success!</strong>

                {{ message }}

        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for message in messages %}
    {% if 'error' in message.tags %}
        <div class="alert alert-error">
            <a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
            <strong>Error!</strong>

                {{ message }}

        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% for message in messages %}
    {% if 'info' in message.tags %}
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            <a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
            <strong>INFO!</strong>

                {{ message }}

        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you really need to perform the loop again?  Looks like doing an `{% elif 'error' in message.tags %}` (or a completely independent `if` after the first one) in the first loop should also work, no?

Answer (score 1):

I managed with template tags only:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% regroup messages by tags as messages %}
    <div id="messages">
    {% for tags in messages %}
        <ul class="{{ tags.grouper }}">
            {% for message in tags.list %}
                <li>{{ message|capfirst }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

The key is the [{% regroup %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) tag.

This still has an some issues because the `tags` attribute includes the `extra_tags` of the [message](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#the-message-class) so if you make use of it you will get additional `<ul>` groups.

In future versions ([probably 1.7](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21421)), there will be a `level_tag` attribute so that issue will be gone soon.

---

(As soon as the `level_tag` attribute is available)

```
{% if messages %}
    {% regroup messages by level_tag as messages %}
    <div id="messages">
    {% for level in messages %}
        <ul class="{{ level.grouper }}">
            {% for message in level.list %}
                <li>{{ message|capfirst }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Good answer for displaying all the messages

Comment: Honestly, best answer I've seen on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

you can use following to check message tags.

`{% if message.tags == "error" %}
    your code here
{% endif %}`

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it with [{% regroup %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) tag but you have to use [dictsort filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-dictsort) aswell if you want to work properly. So firstly, tags should be sort by name and then group:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% regroup messages|dictsort:"tags" by tags as message_list  %}

    {% for tags in message_list %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ tags.grouper }}">
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                    {% for message in tags.list %}
                        <li>
                              {{ message }}
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: you are making simple things complicated