# How send data between views

Tags: django, django-views

I am writing a web based application that has a same login form in every page,so when user submit login form data sent to '/login/' page that corresponde view to this url will check the data has submitted and if input data was incorrect app must back to previews view and on that view in login form i must write a error that indicate that user entered incorrect data,so my question is how can i send data from login view to previous view(like home) that user entered incorrect data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sessions ... specifically [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/)

example from docs:

```
messages.add_message(request, CRITICAL, 'A serious error occurred.')
```

and related question 
[Displaying Django Messages Framework Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697533/displaying-django-messages-framework-messages)

Answer (score 1):

In your `login` view, you use `HttpResponseRedirect` to send your user to your `home` view if the login is successful.

If the login is not successful, show the user the login form along with some error message that you can show the user if needed.

At the `home` view, you check if the user is logged in - if not, use `HttpResponseRedirect` to send them to the `login` view.