# Django messaging framework - how to only display success messages

Tags: python, django

I'm using the Django messaging framework to display feedback messages. I can't display one the success messages.

Here's adapted code from the solution [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697533/displaying-django-messages-framework-messages) and the docs:

```
{% for message in messages.success %}
    {% if 'success' in message.tags %}
    <div class="success-message">{{ message }}</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This yields nothing. If I use something less discriminate, it renders my messages perfectly fine:

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

The view creates the messages like this:

```
messages.success(request, "here's a sample success message")
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using django 1.9.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're attempting to iterate over `messages.success`, which isn't a list.  Instead iterate over `messages` itself, and check for success:

```
{% for message in messages %}
    {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.SUCCESS %}
    <div class="success-message">{{ message }}</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

In fact, the only problem in your initial example is attempting to iterate over `messages.success` rather than `messages`.  Your tags check should also work, even if it isn't quite as 'clean':

```
{% for message in messages %}
    {% if 'success' in message.tags %}
    <div class="success-message">{{ message }}</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Steve, this doesn't seem to work. Sorry for the tardy reply, I'm just having trouble replicating the error on the shell because of a weird `django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware` not installed bug (it is installed and `django.contrib.messages` imports fine).

Comment: That's frustrating.  Your `if 'success' in message.tags` should work instead.

Comment: Does the 'context_processors' option of the DjangoTemplates backend defined in your TEMPLATES setting contain 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'?

Comment: Good thinking, but yes it does.

Comment: I've modified the answer - can you try simply removing the .success part of your initial attempt?

Comment: That worked, many thanks! That's kind of weird; I think your first answer should work because message levels have been around since 1.7 I think, and I'm using 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `==`-operator instead of `in`. And there is no need for use `messages.success`.

```
{% for message in messages %}
    {% if 'success' == message.tags %}
    <div class="success-message">{{ message }}</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: .tags can contain multiple entries, so equality isn't necessarily the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

Message.success is not iterable. Thats why you are getting no message. You can also make use of the method get_success_message in your view to render only success messages.

Answer (score 0):

By checking the `change` parameter, it'd be a piece of cake:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        """
        Override the `save_model()` method to restrict changes on existing objects.

        If an attempt is made to change an existing object, an error message is set.
        """
        if change:
            # Only show messages with `ERROR` level.
            messages.set_level(request, messages.ERROR)
            messages.error(request, 'No changes are permitted...')
        else:
            # Normal flow:
            super(YourClassAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

- The `change` parameter passed to the `save_model()` method indicates whether the action is `create` or `update`. If `update` is `True`, the object is being updated; otherwise, it's being created.
- The effect of `messages.set_level(request, messages.ERROR)` is that only messages with a level of `ERROR` or higher (which there are no any higher level in Django's default message levels than `ERROR`).
- Also, we don't have to reset the message level. Because once the request ends, the level will go back to its default.
- You can get the default level with `messages.get_level(request=request)` and log/print it in the working method. The output would be an [integer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/messages/#creating-custom-message-levels):

  | Level Constant | Value |
  | --- | --- |
  | DEBUG | 10 |
  | INFO | 20 |
  | SUCCESS | 25 |
  | WARNING | 30 |
  | ERROR | 40 |